# What to do when I want to update the upper limit of a range partition of a table (Oracle 11gR2)?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I made a mistake to a production table for the table's partition upper limit, now I would like to update the table's latest partition to a smaller value. Is there a simple way to do it without off the load the data and re-create the partition with smaller upper limit value, then load the data back? Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Split the upper partition, and drop the new highest partition
2. Exchange the partition with a newly created table, drop the now-empty upper partition, add a new upper partition, and exchange the table with it.

The first option would be the better one, I'd expect -- I believe that in 11g splitting a partition is optimised if the data is only going to be contained in one of the new partitions.

Comment: thx much David! I did the 2nd choice worked perfectly. I saw a link from Tom Kyte for the syntax which said need to mimic down to the indexes for the intermittent table, but i did it without create any index on the intermittent table since the original table only has local partitioned indexes, worked beautifully!

Comment: actually Tom is right, the indexes even local partitioned are in need to be taking care of. If swapped without taking care the indexes, then afterwards, need to rebuild those indexed for that partition.